# jQuery script not importing in django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to import my js files into my django template. But it is not importing while css import is working fine.

If I try to import using direct http links of these files, then they are working fine but if I download these files into my myApp/static/js folder, they are not working. Here's my template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/FormStyle.css' %}">
**<script type = "text/javascript" src="{% static "js\validateForm.js" %}" ></script>**
**<script type = "text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.validate.min.js' %)"></script>**
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>

 <div class = "formArea">
<div class = "fileForm">
    <form id = 'formFile' enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
        <div class = "formFields">
            <label for = "file"> {{ form.file.label }} </label>
            {{ form.file }}
            {{ form.file.errors }}
        </div>
        <div class = "formFields">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>    </div>   <script>
 $(document).ready(function()    {
 $('#formFile').validate({
       rules:   {
            'file': {   required: true, extension: "txt|jpe?g|png|gif"  }  },
       messages: {
            'file': {   required: 'Please Upload a File!',
                extension: 'Only Image & txt Files are allowed!' }}
});
 }); </script>
```

Comment: Please share your `settings.py`. Also you have a backslash inside `js\validateForm.js`. Revert to forward slash like this: `js/validateForm.js`

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/FileProject\FileApp\static/',
]`

Comment: Here's a snippet of my static section in settings.py. 
and the import is not even working with forward slash.

Comment: It's not a good practice to hardcode paths like this. You should use `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` as it is originally generated by `./manage.py startproject`.

Comment: Are you actually loading jQuery itself anywhere?

Comment: Actually the problem is that the js libraries are successfully importing from the direct web links but not getting imported from the directory when I download them.